# Getting X-Frame-Options as 'SameOrigin' only in ios and that too for a single url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, x-frame-options, sitecore8.1

I am getting "Refused to display 'http://www.example.com/example/'
in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'." only in ios But  working fine in android. Even in ios also, I am getting this error only for this url. Remaining pages are getting loaded fine in iframe. Please help me to check where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved after several trial and error workouts. The reason is in IOS (safari browser), when a redirect is there in a page, the request headers are getting inherited from intermediate page instead of redirected page. Now, we are checking the condition whether the current page is redirected one or not and updating the headers accordingly